# Mutually recursive lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, boost-asio

This is a boost::asio udp echo demo based on a [boost asio example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp).

The meat of this version using C++ lambda is less than half the size of the boost example one, but gcc tells me that `received` is not visible in `recv_from`.

It pains me to have to write this in a more verbose manner.  Can some C++ guru help me with a trick to define mutually recursive lambdas?

```
class server {
public:
  server(io_service& io_service, short port)
    : socket_(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port)) {
    auto recv_from = [&,received]() {
      socket_.async_receive_from(buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,
                                 received);
    };
    auto received = [&,recv_from](const error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
      if (!error && bytes_transferred > 0) {
        socket_.async_send_to(buffer(data_, bytes_transferred), sender_endpoint_,
                              [&](const error_code&, size_t) {
                                recv_from();
                              });
      } else {
        recv_from(); // loop
      }
    };
    recv_from();
  }

private:
  udp::socket socket_;
  udp::endpoint sender_endpoint_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};
```

Edit, solution: I needed to add this:

```
std::function<void(const error_code&, size_t)> received;
```

to make it easy for the type-inference engine (I'm spoiled having programmed Haskell)

Edit2: There are lifetime issues so that won't work.

Comment: How about you use normal `static` functions? Problem gone, more readable.

Comment: I see that my question is probably a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067988/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c0x?rq=1

Comment: +Seth Carnegie With static functions it is less readable because there is 50% more boilerplate.

Comment: Oh, I see you are using the capture. Then use non-static functions. There's hardly any extra boiler plate, if any.

Comment: Look at the link at the beginning of the question.  I count 40 vs 18 lines.

Comment: Their code is doing a lot more than yours is. Or in a different way that takes more lines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26117/discussion-between-user239558-and-seth-carnegie)

Comment: Note that `std::function<void(const error_code&, size_t)>` has costs (it is dynamically dispatched).  In addition, instead of editing your question with the answer, self-answer your question, then mark it as the correct answer.  :)

Comment: Yakk, that begs the question:  How do you do recursive lambdas with little/no cost? (given that the scope holding the lambda doesn't exist)

Comment: There is a reoccurring theme of readability between the question, comments, and chat logs.  An alternative solution to less verbosity and arguable more readability is stackless coroutines.  Boost.Asio provides an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server4/).  Additionally, Christopher Kohlhoff, the author of Boost.Asio, has a few blogs entries about this approach on his [blog](http://blog.think-async.com/2009/08/composed-operations-coroutines-and-code.html).

Comment: twansbury, those coroutines are fantastic! Thanks! My only issue with the last blog post is that he could probably do more with lambdas, and less with less boost::bind magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:

There are actually no less than three problems with my code.

1. I have been careful to *copy* the `received` and `recv_from` into the corresponding closures so that they would be available when the constructor goes out of scope.
   Unfortunately, the closures [go out of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941562/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-c-lambda-expression) at the same time as the constructor.  Thus the `[&, xxx]` copying of `xxx` makes no sense.
2. The type of at least(?) one of the lambdas must be fixed to please the type inference engine.
3. But that doesn't solve issue #1. To fix the lifetime issue, I should have stored the closure objects in the `server` object.

So I think this is close to what I need to do:

```
class server {
 public:
   server(io_service& io_service, short port)
     : socket_(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port)) {
    recv_from = [&]() {
       socket_.async_receive_from(buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,
                                 received);
    };
    received = [&](const error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
      if (!error && bytes_transferred > 0) {
        socket_.async_send_to(buffer(data_, bytes_transferred), sender_endpoint_,
                              [&](const error_code&, size_t) {
                                recv_from();
                              });
      } else {
        recv_from(); // loop
      }
    };
    recv_from();
  }

private:
  udp::socket socket_;
  udp::endpoint sender_endpoint_;
  std::function<void(const error_code&, size_t)> received;
  std::function<void()> recv_from;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};
```