# Controlling the lifetime of a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, callback, function-pointers

I have a piece of code which calls an [async rdma-write](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rdma_post_write). The rdma API receives a *void* context* which I would like to use to pass a callback to be called when the operation finishes.

```
void invoke_async_operation(... some stuff to capture ...) {
  ...
  MyCallBackType* my_callback = // Create callback somehow
  rdma_post_write(..., my_callback);
  ...
}

void on_complete(void* context) {
  (*(MyCallbackType*)context)();
}
```

I thought using a lambda here would be best, because it will easily capture all the context which is required to the later callback invokement. However I saw in [What is the lifetime of a C++ lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941562/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-c-lambda-expression) that a lambda lifetime is limited to the scope where it was defined.

**Note that I can't copy the lambda, because context is a pointer.**

What is the correct approach here? Should I insist on using lambdas and prolong their lifetime somehow, or is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: [Why are you asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @StoryTeller need to call it somewhere in the future by a different thread.

Comment: The other thread is supposed to `new` something?

Comment: Since I suspect the answer is no, it seems the Y to your X is how one would package a lambda for multi-threaded execution.

Comment: If you pass your lambda object via copy to "something" the lifetime of the lambda object is "long enough" ;). Maybe the cost of copy disturbs you, think about the cost of new!

Comment: @StoryTeller The current thread should call an async operation, and pass it a callback pointer. The other thread will be run once the async operation finished, and should invoke the callbcack.

Comment: @StoryTeller note that the async operation receives a (uint64_t context), so not sure how to pass it a copy of the lambda.

Comment: @EladWeiss - I don't know if you are bound to some architecture, but the better approach is to ditch a CB + data pair, and instead pass a type erasing functor (like `std::function`) for greatest flexibility.

Comment: @StoryTeller also tried std::move, but got an error about xvalue. (Sorry I'm new to this)

Comment: @EladWeiss - No need for apologies. No one is born knowing this. I think you should add a [mcve]. That way a solution could be tailored for your specific case and all of its constraints.

Comment: @StorryTeller Will do. Thanks. On this question or create a new one?

Comment: Better improve, I think

Comment: A lambda is just a syntactic sugar for a function object (one with an `operator()` member). Whatever you can do with one, you can do with the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Lifetime of a lambda

The object that represents the lamda expression and allows to invoke it, obeys indeed the usual scoping rules.

However this object can be copied (e.g passing it as argument to a function or a constructor, or assigning it to a global, or whatever else you want to do) so that the lambda can be invoked at any later point, even after the scope it was initially defined in is left.

Because of exactly this potentially long survival of lambdas, you can find quite a few questions, blogs or books that will advise on careful use of the lambda capture, especially if captured by reference, because the lambda itself (and not its anonymous proxy object) can be called even after the referred objects are destroyed.

#### Your callback issue

You are constraint in your design by the use of an OS callback that can only convey a raw pointer that was passed to it when the callback was set up.

The way to approach this could be to use a [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object of the standard [`<functional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) library.  Here a small function to show you how it works:

```
function<void()>* preparatory_work() {
    auto l = [](){ cout<< "My lambda is fine !" <<endl; } ;  // lambda 
    function<void ()> f = l;                                 // functor
    auto p = new function<void()>(l);                        // a functor on the heap
    
    l();  // inovke the lambda object 
    f();  // invoke the functor 
    (*p)(); // invoike functor via a pointer 

    return p; 
}
```

Function objects are as handy to use as any other object and as easy to declare as function pointers.  They are however much more powerful than function pointers, because they can refer basically to any callable object.

As you see, in the example above, I allocated a function objet with new, and returned its pointer. So you could indeed later invoke this function:

```
int main() {
    auto fcp = preparatory_work();  // fcp is a pointer 
    (*fcp)();
                                    // and even with casting as you would like
    void *x = (void*)fcp; 
    (*(function<void()>*)x)();   // YES !!! 
}
```

Here an [online demo](https://ideone.com/gZzEiJ)

Comment: I think copying is not an option (edited the question). So I guess the global option remains. That means map, since I can have many.

Comment: @EladWeiss with your edit I understand better your question.  Look at the solution in my edit.