# No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Tags: c++, lambda, conditional-operator, std-function

I have a strange error I don't really understand, with VS2013.
It's just a simplification of my real problem resulting in the same error.

```
std::function<bool()> x = (someCondition == true)
    ? []() { return true; }
    : []() { return false; };
```

VS Compiler error is:

```
1>f:\test\cppconsoleapplication\cppconsoleapplication.cpp(497): error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'main::<lambda_96d01fe3721e46e4e8217a69a07d151b>' to 'main::<lambda_0d38919a9b2aba5caf910d83eac11776>'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

IntelliSense even came up with this mysterious error message:

```
IntelliSense: more than one operator "?" matches these operands:
        built-in operator "expression ? pointer : pointer"
        built-in operator "expression ? pointer : pointer"
        built-in operator "expression ? pointer : pointer"
        built-in operator "expression ? pointer : pointer"
        operand types are: lambda []bool ()->bool : lambda []bool ()->bool  f:\Test\CppConsoleApplication\CppConsoleApplication.cpp 496
```

whereas the following compiles

```
std::function<bool()> x = []() { return true; };

if (someCondition == false)
    x = []() { return false; };
```

Is it just one of VisualStudio's bugs or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: VS2013 does not have complete support for C++11 features. Try VS2015. Also you can try explicitely cast one lambda into function pointer to force deduction of common type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is fine, MSVC is wrong to reject it. According to [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other):

> The type and value category of the conditional expression E1 ? E2 : E3 are determined according to the following rules:
>   [1-4 Don't apply]
>   5) Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. **If E2 and E3 do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, overload resolution is performed using the built-in candidates below to attempt to convert the operands to built-in types.** If the overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, the selected conversions are applied and the converted operands are used in place of the original operands for step 6.

The aforementioned built-in candidates include a candidate that attempts to convert both operands to a pointer. As both lambdas have an empty capture list, they are convertible to `bool(*)()`, so this candidate should be chosen. (The other candidates do not fit, so the pointer one is not ambiguous.)

To summarize:

```
(someCondition == true)
    ? []() { return true; }
    : []() { return false; };
```

should convert both lambdas to `bool(*)()` and yield a pointer-to-function that, when invoked, has the same effect as the selected lambda. This pointer is not dangling, independent of the lifetime of the lambda objects. (Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026170/lifetime-of-lambda-objects-in-relation-to-function-pointer-conversion).)
The resulting function pointer can then be assigned to the `std::function`.

Note that both lambdas having an empty capture list is vital. If one of the lambdas would capture something, the conversion to pointer would not work anymore and the code would be ill-formed.

You can probably help your old MSVC by explicitly casting one or both lambdas to `bool(*)()` or `std::function<bool()>`. The latter would also allow you to use lambdas with a non-empty capture list. ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7370c29c3c508642))

---

To explain the diagnostics your IDE gives you:

The compiler error seems to stem from step 3) from the list I linked: It tries to convert one operand to the type of the other one and fails.

IntelliSense seems to have the right idea at least and complains about the overload resolution as described in step 5). Why it finds too many candidates I don't know. This is a bug.