# Non-capturing lambda lifecycle

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm having a trouble finding a definitive answer if the following code is correct in both cases, with non-capturing lambda and with call of a static function. I'm pretty sure the latter is fine, what I'm concerned about is the lifetime of a lambda when "defined" inside another block/function call, etc. The code seems to work fine but I'd still prefer to know why... Does the non-capturing lambda end up defined as some kind of anonymous (hidden) global symbol so it's basically the same as that static function?

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
class Listener {
public:
    void event() { printf("event() called\n"); }

    static void forwardEvent(void* userArg) { static_cast<Listener*>(userArg)->event(); }
};

class Producer {
    using Listener = void(void* arg);
    Listener* listener_;
    void* userArg_;

public:
    void attachListener(Listener* listener, void* userArg) {
        listener_ = listener;
        userArg_ = userArg;
    }

    void issueEvent() { listener_(userArg_); }
};

int main() {
    Listener listener;
    Producer producer;

    {  // different scope, in case that makes a difference...
        producer.attachListener(Listener::forwardEvent, &listener);
    }
    producer.issueEvent();

    {  // different scope, in case that makes a difference...
        producer.attachListener([](void* userArg) { static_cast<Listener*>(userArg)->event(); }, &listener);
    }
    producer.issueEvent();
}
```

Comment: @TonyTannous Not entirely sure that's a dupe. OP is specifically asking about *non-capturing* lambdas. (there's probably a dupe for that anyway).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lifetime of lambda objects in relation to function pointer conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026170/lifetime-of-lambda-objects-in-relation-to-function-pointer-conversion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so your nested `Listener` definition is this.

```
using Listener = void(void* arg);
Listener* listener_;
```

Basically, you deal with good old function pointers. Now when you pass an argument for the function pointer, you do this

```
producer.attachListener([](void* userArg) { static_cast<Listener*>(userArg)->event(); }, &listener);
```

The non-capturing lambda is converted to a function pointer via an implicit conversion. This function pointer is

1. guaranteed to be valid, and points at a function that
2. behaves exactly the same as if the lambda's `operator()` was called.

Functions "exist" for the entire duration of the program, and their addresses never become dangling. So your code has well-defined behavior as far as using the pointer obtained from the lambda expression is concerned.

Comment: As an aside, having two "Listener" types in the code sample is a bit confusing. I would suggest calling the nested type something else.

Comment: > Functions "exist" for the entire duration of the program, and their addresses never become dangling.

That's what I wanted to hear, thanks